# How does SQL Server calculate the sample size when sp_updatestats is run without explicitly setting a sample size?

Tags: sql-server, database

The SQL Server documentation for [sp_updatestats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173804.aspx) states that:

> If 'resample' is not specified, sp_updatestats updates statistics by using the default sampling.

How exactly does SQL Server calculate the default sample size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good question.  If you're interested in statistics, you might want to give Elisabeth Redei's excellent blog post a read:

[Lies, Damned Lies and Statistics](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/elisabeth_redei/archive/2009/03/01/lies-damned-lies-and-statistics-part-i.aspx)

It explains that, as the table size increases, the default sampling rate becomes insufficient to accurately represent the table's contents.  It also provides a formula that she states is used in calculating the default sample set size (Rowmodctr 500 + 20% of total rows).

Comment: that's wrong, is the formula to determine if a statistics is out dated and then fires un update.
the default sample size must be calculated with some other formula that I'm searching too.